# vuejs insert image in raw html

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I want to style some text from an object property in an array, therefore I use [v-html](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html). But when I insert a picture with these syntaxs, it doesn't work.

```
<img :src="@/assets/image.png" alt="image description">
//or this
<img :src="require('@/assets/image.png') alt="image description'">
//or this
<img src="@/assets/image.png" alt="image description">
```

What's the correct way to do it?

Comment: Your motivation for using `v-html` seems misguided. Why do you think `v-html` is needed for that?

Comment: @tony19 i have an array full of objects, in each object there are 3 properties. they're all strings. I want to add image in one particular of the properties therefore I use v-html :/ so is it wrong? sorry, im new here

Comment: Just throw your markup in a template, and use [`v-bind`](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-bind) for data bindings. Don't use `v-html` for this.

Answer (score 3):

`v-html` will render value as HTML without any change in the browser.

So you can't pass vue or javascript code (`:src="@/assets/image.png"`) to this.

From the [documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-html):

`the contents are inserted as plain HTML - they will not be compiled as Vue templates`

Comment: oh, okay. i actually was just trying with different methods.. because when i use `src="@/assets/image.png"` it doesn't work. but thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 0):

```html
<img src="@/assets/image.png" alt="image description">
```

This is correct, if the image is not loading then you have not put it in the correct directory.

`@/assets` are loaded from `src/assets` and the compiler optimizes and builds them out to `public` dir.

It is an alias:

`@` = `src`